# use of universal providers and mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I created an asp.net mvc 4 application, and added universal providers, because I need to create a custom membership provider that read users data from a my sql database.

When I work on the developer workstation it's all ok, but when I deploy on the server, where there is not Sql Server installed i receive an error. trying to open DefaultConnection.

In the **InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute** that is created from the wizard, I have this:
**WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: false);**
this call initialize the db connection, do nothing, and is not used by the custom membership provider, but must be done at startup.
the connection string is:

*add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=...;Initial Catalog=...;User id=...;Password=..." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />*

the problem is that I don't know how to configure to use a mysql db and pass this control in the startup of the application.

If I have to install it in a server with Sql server installed, I configure it properly, and after the initial call the mysql membership provider works without problem, but i have problems when i cannot use this workaround, and exception is raised at the call to InitializeDatabaseConnection.

How can I fix this problem?